# Export Data to CSV

Tags: c#

I try to make an .exe file that can read global parameter from text file and export the data from database to csv file

Basicly i can read the connection string and read the command from the text file, however i cant create the csv file.

my code is like below

```
static class CsvGenerator
{
public static string gb_Localconn = DBManager.GetParameter("ConnStr=");
public static string gb_Delimiter = DBManager.GetParameter("Delimiter=");
public static string gb_Quote = DBManager.GetParameter("Quote=");
public static string gb_QuoteType = DBManager.GetParameter("Quote_Type=");
public static string gb_CsvOutput = DBManager.GetParameter("Output_path=");
public static string gb_Prefix = DBManager.GetParameter("Output_Prefix=");
public static string gb_LogOutput = DBManager.GetParameter("Logfile_path=");
public static string gb_VesselList = DBManager.GetParameter("Vessel_list=");
private static DataTable dt;
private static int i;


public static void Main()
{
    StreamReader oRead = new StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Query.cfg");

    string txtline = null;
    string QueryName = null;
    string query = null;
    while (oRead.Peek() != -1)

        try
        {
            txtline = oRead.ReadLine();
            if (txtline.IndexOf(":") != -1)
            {
                QueryName = txtline.Substring(0, txtline.IndexOf(":"));
                query = txtline.Substring(txtline.IndexOf(":") + 1, txtline.Length - QueryName.Length - 1);
                query = query.Replace("|Vessels|", gb_VesselList);
                MessageBox.Show(query);

                {

                    {
                        dt = DBManager.DBExecuteSelect(query, gb_Localconn);

                        DataColumn dcol = null;
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            MessageBox.Show(dcol.ToString());
                    }
                    DataRow drow = null;
                    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        MessageBox.Show(drow.ToString());


                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            {
            }




        }
}
}
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You're not even attempting to create a CSV file.. can you show us that part?

Answer (score 0):

Refer following code which is working for me:

```
var lines = new string[5][];

var csvFile = string.Join("\r\n", lines.Select(words =>
              string.Join(",", words.Select(word =>
                  "\"" + word.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")))));

File.WriteAllText("yourFileName.csv", csvFile);
```

For other details about c# and csv import and export , go through following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[CSV Helper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki) is a good tool you can use to write CSV files.

I would rather recommend you to have Model classes to create the files.